How to use devtools to re-render charts created with Rechart?
I am an end user of a website using Rechart to show some charts. I cannot reach the React code.
Is it possible to remove a line in a LineChart and re-render the whole chart via the devtools in the browser?
The reason to do this is that there is a data line whose values are larger than the variation of the other data line. I want to remove one line to see the variation of the other line clearlier.
That website use React Fiber.

It's unlikely you will be able to do this without significant reverse engineering of the website, and doing so is definitely out of the scope of a StackOverflow question.


Open DevTools
Inspect the chart and locate the  element of the line you want to hide.
Right-click on the element and choose “Delete Element” or use the console:

document.querySelector('path.your-target-class').style.display = 'none';


Only hiding the line doesn't scale the chart with the remaining data, so I still cannot make the variation of the remaining data larger in the chart.
